# Bash - How to initiate GUI programs minimized?

Tags: bash, firefox, terminal, x11, window-managers

I may want to open a couple of Firefox windows for some reason. If I were to plan that for some schedule, instantly *shack* *shock* *tack* a couple of windows pop-up which is kinda annoying. So, I wonder if I can run `firefox` minimized from the terminal?

Possible workaround solutions I thought:

1. Editing the prefs.js file under profile folder. However, I couldn't find a `user_pref()` for Firefox to parse.
2. By X11 maybe? So, I researched about `xdotool`. However, after getting the window IDs and waiting for firefox to open, still, I get the *shack* *shock* *tack* right on my face.
   What I used is: `xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool search --name 'Mozilla Firefox')`
3. Playing with the window manager. So, I also looked over `wmctrl`. Unfortunately this didn't even minimize my windows. What I used is: `wmctrl -r "0x03e0002c" -b toggle,hidden # 0x03e0002c: the firefox window id I get from: wmctrl -l`

I believe a solution right at execution time should be done. A one liner would be very useful.

Comment: Which window manager are you using ?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu at the moment but I would like a more universal solution rather than wm dependent. I'm thinking about keeping track of the window property of whatever program and unmapping it immediately.

Comment: @Philippe For instance, I use iwm on arch for daily usage with a lot of personal preferences set. Yet, I still use debian, fedora, etc. for package management.